# Sprite kit CGPoint not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-engine, game-physics, sprite-kit

I am writing a game in Sprite Kit and I am having a problem with CGPoint, at the moment if the phone is portrait the object comes in from the right side of the screen and goes to the left, I need it to come in from the top of the screen and fall to the bottom, How do I make it spawn from the top of the screen? At The moment it also travels right, I want to to travel downwards Here is all the code relevant to the "missile"..

```
static inline CGPoint CGPointAdd(const CGPoint a, const CGPoint b)
{
return CGPointMake(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}

static inline CGPoint CGPointMultiplyScalar(const CGPoint a, const CGFloat b)
{
return CGPointMake(a.x  * b, a.y * b);
}



-(void)addMissile
{
//initalizing spaceship node
SKSpriteNode *missile;
missile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"red-missile.png"];
[missile setScale:.01];

//Adding SpriteKit physicsBody for collision detection
missile.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:missile.size];
missile.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleCategory;
missile.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
missile.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = shipCategory;
missile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
missile.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
missile.name = @"missile";

//selecting random y position for missile
//int t = arc4random() % 300;
missile.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);

[self addChild:missile];
}



- (void)moveObstacle
{
    NSArray *nodes = self.children;//1

for(SKNode * node in nodes){
    if (![node.name  isEqual: @"bg"] && ![node.name  isEqual: @"ship"]) {
        SKSpriteNode *ob = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
        CGPoint obVelocity = CGPointMake(-OBJECT_VELOCITY, 0);
        CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(obVelocity,_dt);

        ob.position = CGPointAdd(ob.position, amtToMove);
        if(ob.position.y < 100)
        {
            [ob removeFromParent];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the missile animation is simple so you don't need **GDPointAdd** and **MultiplyByScalar** in this case

if you need a missile that moves from top to bottom here is the code

```
- (void)shootMissile {
     // Sprite Kit knows that we are working with images so we don't need to pass the image’s extension
     SKSpriteNode *missile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"red-missile"];
     // Position the missile outside the top
     missile.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height + missile.size.height/2);
     // Add the missile to the scene
     [self addChild:missile];

     // Here is the Magic
     // Run a sequence
     [missile runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
         // Move the missile and Specify the animation time
         [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-(self.size.height + missile.size.height) duration:3],
         // When the missile is outside the bottom
         // The missile will disappear
         [SKAction removeFromParent]                               ]
     ]];
}
```

All you need is call this function when you want to shoot the missile

Now you can add all your physics to the missile

Good Luck!!

Comment: How do i update it? my current method is not working

Comment: if you call shootMissile from touchesBegan a missile will appear every time you touch the screen if you call it inside update a missile will appear every second. or what do you mean with update it? give me more info and i'll help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
- (void)moveObstacle
{
    NSArray *nodes = self.children;//1

    for(SKNode * node in nodes){
        if (![node.name  isEqual: @"bg"] && ![node.name  isEqual: @"ship"]) {
            SKSpriteNode *ob = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
            CGPoint obVelocity = CGPointMake(0, -OBJECT_VELOCITY);
            CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(obVelocity,_dt);

            ob.position = CGPointAdd(ob.position, amtToMove);
            if(ob.position.y < 0)
            {
                [ob removeFromParent];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though I don't know what does `_dt` stand for.